# I want a dropdown box to appear beneath the top navbar when active. How can I achieve this stacking order without the dropdown overlapping the navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs

So I want my dropdown menu component to slide in from the top of the page, however, it currently slides over the top navbar.

The relevant JavaScript logic within my dropdown component is as follows;

```
return (
    <div className="category-dropdown" ref={menuRef}>
      <button onClick={toggleDropdown} className="dropdown-button">
        <div className="icon-container">
          {isOpen ? (
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
          ) : (
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
          )}
        </div>
      </button>
      <ul className={`category-list ${isOpen ? "active" : "inactive"}`}>
        <div className="category-list-header">Shop By Category</div>
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <li key={index} className="category-item">
            <Link href={`/category/${slugify(category)}`}>
              {titleIfy(category)}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
```

Then I import the component on my layout here;

```
      <div className="top-navbar-container">
        <CategoryDropdown />
        <div className="top-navbar-wrapper">
        </div>
      </div>
```

The relevant CSS styles are as follows;

```
.top-navbar-container {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #4fbbff;
  padding: 4px 12px; /* Default padding */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 1px; /* Border only at the bottom */
  border-color: #0083d7;
  height: 75px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-navbar-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Align the logo with the rest of the navbar */
}

.category-dropdown,
.user-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #003f66;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px; /* Force it down vertically */
}

.category-list::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.user-info-list::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: 125px;
}

.category-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 68px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 275px;
  display: none;
  z-index: -100;
}

.user-info-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 68px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 275px;
  display: none;
  right: -110px;
}

.category-list.active,
.user-info-list.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.85, 0, 1);
  transform-origin: top;
}

.category-list.inactive,
.user-info-list.inactive {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.85, 0, 1);
  top: -1000px;
  transform-origin: top;
}

.category-item,
.user-item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

I tried adding a z-index value to the top navbar, a lower value to the dropdown, etc, but this did not solve the issue. However, I was able to fix this entire issue by removing position: sticky, top: 0 and width: calc(100% - 0px) from the .top-navbar-container. So is it possible to get this working while maintaining the sticky property of the navbar?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)!